# Probability Theory: Conditional Independence and Independence

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I have the following definition of conditional independence: $X$ and $Y$ are called conditionally independent given a sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$ of $\mathcal{F}$ if for all bounded Borel functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, it holds: $E[f(X)g(Y)|\mathcal{G}]=E[f(X)|\mathcal{G}]E[g(Y)|\mathcal{G}]$.
However, I can not really get that.
In particular, what is really the difference between conditional independence and "unconditional independence"? Can someone maybe provide an example showing how and why these two things differ. Maybe an example that conditional independence is not implied by "unconditional/regular?!" independence? 
Thank you.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between independence and conditional independence of events? This would be a good start. Wikipedia article for this is also a good first source http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence This article contains examples which you asked for.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $(X,Y)$ uniform on $\{-1,1\}^2$, then $(X,Y)$ is independent but is not independent conditionally on $Z=XY$. For example, $E(XY\mid Z)=Z$ while $E(X\mid Z)=E(Y\mid Z)=0$ hence $E(XY\mid Z)\ne E(X\mid Z)E(Y\mid Z)$.

Similar counterexamples show that conditional independence does not imply independence.